# How to run a virtual machine on windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, virtual-machine

I want to play Empire Earth 2 with friends, however it doesn't work on Windows 8. I would thus like to know the best way and how to run a virtual machine on my computer with either windows 7 or 8?

Comment: windows 8 has hyper-v built into it I would use that.

Comment: @Ramhound: I'm pretty sure it is only included in the Pro/Enterprise versions of Windows 8 and can't legally be used with the Standard version. Unfortunately he hasn't said what exactly what version he is using.

Comment: Unfortunately I am using the standard version.

Comment: @James - I am more then aware of that fact.  In the context of the suggestion I mention thats what I (personally) would use.  The question isn't even all that clear, he is using Windows 8, but wants a VM solution for both Windows 7 and Windows 8.  Furthermore EE2 works just fine on Windows 8 in compatability mode.

Comment: @Ramhound I've tried it, and it doesn't work for me. I had to use a bat file to get it running, but then online doesn't work with Game Ranger.

Comment: @user2396852 - Sounds like the major problem you have is with Game Ranger supporting Windows 8.  It hasn't been updated in 5 years based on the information I have.

Comment: All my other games work fine with it, even games that came out before EE2. @Ramhound But yeah, it's quite outdated software.

Comment: Have you read these articles: http://www.easywinclan.com/t1603-empire-earth-2-windows-8-81-fix-empire-earth-2-the-art-of-supremacy-windows-8-81-fix-works-with-gameranger and http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-gaming/my-empire-earth-2-is-not-compatible-with-windows-8/a549dbed-cb21-4432-9a22-74a9d18bbc91 and http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lCjJfuxfBBM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use VMWare Player (which is free for personal use) or you could try VirtualBox by Oracle, which is again, free.

VirtualBox : https://www.virtualbox.org/

Vmware Player : https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/free#desktop_end_user_computing/vmware_player/6_0

I've used both, and both work fine for my needs, although I'm not using the VM's to play games.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Windows 8 Pro you should be able to use Hyper-V. Lots of VMware fanboys like to rag on Hyper-V, but its come a long way in recent years, if you're using just plain 'ol Win8 (Not Pro) You're stuck with Virtualbox and\or VMWare